# How to implement home screen widget for iOS app with multiple schemes for different apps?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, home-screen-widget

I have a flutter app with two flavors and I want to add home screen widget for iOS deployment for only one flavor of app.

Each flavor of my app is corresponding to a unique bundle ID (`my.domain.app1` and `my.domain.app2`).

I set scheme in Xcode following [flutter tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors).

I created home screen widget in iOS using [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/flutter-home-screen-widgets#2).

I give bundle ID for my home screen widget `my.domain.app2.homeWidget` as I want home widget for only app2. I do not need home widget for app1.

I try running app2 and it has no issue.
However,  I try debugging my app1, it causes this error.
`Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier`

I tried removing `homeWidget` from `Build Phases > Embed Foundation Extensions`  but it removes my home widget from both app1 and app2. I cannot keep home widget for only one app scheme.

How can I assign home widget in iOS to only `my.domain.app2` but not `my.domain.app1`?